# Flutter - Change image opacity of decoration image in container not going smooth

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I have two containers 'Stack'ed one on top of another.

Both use decorationImage as a background. The one on TOP looks like the following:

```
Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.transparent,
                        image: widget.imageAfter.isEmpty
                            ? const DecorationImage(image: AssetImage('images/camera.png'))
                            : DecorationImage(
                            image: MemoryImage(base64Decode(widget.imageAfter)),
                            colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(Colors.transparent.withOpacity(OPACITY), BlendMode.dstATop),
                            fit: BoxFit.cover),
                        border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 1.0)
                    ),
                  ),
```

I change the value of opacity using a slider. when it goes 1, I can only see the image on top and at value 0 I can see the image at the bottom.

The problem I am facing is that the transition of the image transparency is not smooth when I am moving the slider. I get the result when I stop moving the slider but I am unable to see the transition in a smooth way. I guess this is because flutter is not able to draw the images in time. Is there way to do it?

[image]